# Modifying c++ spidev code from a 10- to 12-bit device

Tags: c++, spi, adc

I'm referencing [this](http://www.hertaville.com/interfacing-an-spi-adc-mcp3008-chip-to-the-raspberry-pi-using-c.html) post to connect to an MCP3208 12-bit ADC. The linked post uses an MCP3008, which is only a 10-bit ADC, so sending/receiving SPI data is slightly different.

Here is the 10-bit code:

```
mcp3008Spi a2d("/dev/spidev0.0", SPI_MODE_0, 1000000, 8);
int a2dVal = 0;
int a2dChannel = 0;
unsigned char data[3];

data[0] = 1;  //  first byte transmitted -> start bit
data[1] = 0b10000000 |( ((a2dChannel & 7) << 4)); // second byte transmitted -> (SGL/DIF = 1, D2=D1=D0=0)
data[2] = 0; // third byte transmitted....don't care

a2d.spiWriteRead(data, sizeof(data) );

a2dVal = 0;
a2dVal = (data[1]<< 8) & 0b1100000000; //merge data[1] & data[2] to get result
a2dVal |=  (data[2] & 0xff);

cout << "The Result is: " << a2dVal << endl;
```

The SPI communication chart for the MCP3008 (10-bit) is as follows:

[image: MCP3008 10-Bit ADC SPI Communications]

The SPI ocmmunication chart for the MCP3208 (12-bit) is as follows:

[image: MCP3208 12-Bit ADC SPI Communications]

As such, the first byte I send (for single-ended measurement of channel 0) should be 00000110, the second byte should be 00000000, and the third can also be 00000000.

How can I modify the example code posted above to reflect this information, including modification of the read and merge of the data[x] bytes?

Answer (score 0):

By cargo cult programming and a lot of trial and error i found this to work for me:

```
import spidev

#                  [         Array of bytes sent             ]                                              
#rdata = spi.xfer2([Start, Config        ,stuffing ,?        ] , speed Hz , delay default 0 , wordlength )
rdata  = spi.xfer2([1    ,(8+channel)<<4 ,255      ,0        ] ,15000     ,0                , 8          )

#rdata is an Array of bytes received
a= (rdata[1]&3)  << 10 # binary AND with 3 -> only last two bits count,  <<shift left by 10 
b=  rdata[2]     <<2   # shift left by 2
c= (rdata[3]&192)>>6   # binary AND with 192 -> only fisrt two bits count, >>shift right by 6
data= a + b + c

print( "a:{}  b:{}  c:{} data:{} ".format(a,b,c,data))
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old question and definitely unrelated to what I had been searching for, I decided to answer it, as the only answer is in Python and does not answer the question.

The real answer to this question, from what I can see, is that almost nothing needs to change. `data[0]` should be changed to your command. To merge the received bytes, you just need to extend the mask used on the lower byte. Aside from those changes, everything should work fine.

To change the command:

```c
data[0] = 0x06;
```

To merge the bytes:

```c
uint16_t val = 0;
val |= (data[1] & 0x0F) << 8;
val |= data[2];
```

This is an old question and I'm sure the OP has figured out the answer by now, but future readers looking for a similar problem might find this answer useful.